# Can a Canadian student with US resident alien status receive the tax treaty benefit after 5 years? If so, how much?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, canada, tax-exemption

I am a Canadian citizen who has studied in the U.S. with a J-1 visa since 5 years ago, which means that I have now become a resident alien.  I am still studying (for an advanced degree) in the U.S.  For the past 5 years as a nonresident alien, I have been using the [Canada-US tax exempt treaty Article XV](https://www.fin.gc.ca/treaties-conventions/usa_-eng.asp).

I have researched that some countries limit the number of years you can use the treaty, but I could not find anything for the Canada-US treaty, nor can I find what the treaty says about being a resident alien in the US.

**So if I still qualify to use the treaty, should I just fill out a [Form 8833](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.irs.gov%2Fpub%2Firs-pdf%2Ff8833.pdf) to get the exemption?** Are there any other forms to fill out?

If I can get the exemption, Article XV states "such remuneration does not exceed ten thousand dollars ($10,000) in the currency of that other State", **does that mean I can only get exempted up to $10k?**  So for example, if I earn $12k, I can only get $10k of exemption, leaving the $2k to be taxed in the U.S.?

Comment: Are you sure it was article XV? I cannot see how it applies to you.

Comment: @littleadv, does it not apply to me anymore if I have made more than $10k in income?

Comment: I don't think it ever applied to you. Based on what have you claimed it?

Comment: littleadv, who do you think it applies to then?

Comment: It applies to people who move to the US on a temporary (up to 6 months) assignment from their Canadian employer. I think you had no right to claim this article as a student, the only article relevant to you is XX.

Comment: Note that other countries do in fact have explicit exemptions for students in J/F status working in the US. But the Canadian treaty doesn't provide you that benefit. So if you acted on advice of another international student from a different country - you may have inadvertently got yourself in trouble by filing a fraudulent return with the IRS (and there's no statute of limitations on tax fraud). I suggest you get a proper advice from a EA/CPA licensed in your State and familiar with the treaty.